# How to ignore selection of all-extension using wild characters [ *.* ]

Tags: batch-file

I m making a utility for name conversion (using ren command) and want to operate ren command only on specific extensions at a time.

To ignore the selection of all extensions I have used below code:

```
set /p extension="Enter Extension (e.g. *.jpg, *.png): "
echo. %extension%  

if %extension%==*.* (
   echo All file extensions can't be renamed. && echo Press any key to exit
   pause >nul
   exit
)
```

But while testing the script if I type [*******.********] instead of [*.*] the above if conditional fails. So please someone guide me how to prevent inputs like **.******?

Thanks

Comment: Would you allow something like `*.doc?`, `*.xls?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change expected inputs to actual extensions (not `*.jpg`, but `.jpg`). Then simply check if the input contains any wildcards (`*` or `?`):

```
set /p extension="Enter Extension (e.g. .jpg, .png): "
echo. %extension%  

echo %extension%|findstr /l "* ?" && (
   echo No wildcards allowed. & echo Press any key to exit
   pause >nul
   exit
)
```

Comment: inputs can't be changed. They are further used in "if exist" command. The "if exist" command is incapable without "\*" in "*.jpg".  don't you think.

Comment: `if exist "*%extension%" echo don't think so...`